# Need to count a running value percentage top 80 percentile number of rows

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a running value expression that color codes (Yellow) when it reaches 80%. The remaining 20% are then without color. I need to count the number of rows that comprise that 80%. 
Here is the expression that's placed in the Background Color properties:

```
=IIF(RunningValue(Sum(CDbl(Fields!qtr_total.Value)), Sum, "Data8020") < 
(Sum(Fields!qtr_totalValue.Value, "Data8020") * .8), "Yellow", "Transparent")
```

I just need to count the number of rows that are marked in yellow.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column with the following expression:

```
=IIF(RunningValue(Sum(CDbl(Fields!qtr_total.Value)), Sum, "Data8020") < 
(Sum(Fields!qtr_totalValue.Value, "Data8020") * .8), 1, 0)
```

and then sum this column to get to the count value. You can **hide** this column so that it wont mess the looks of your report.